# Motor with two endstops using limit switches

Tags: switches, relay, dc-motor, automation, contact

[image: If we start with the above circuit, it will drive motor one way and stop at one of the end stops. Can you suggest an idea to connect the circuit back with reversed polarity if I reverse the supply? The motor should stop and disconnect at the other endstop]I have a circuit where two limit-switches to be wired with motors to do the following functionality. It is to be used in a remotely placed device so that the intervention of microcontroller on the working of the motor should be minimized.

The circuit shall perform the following operation

- When the supply is positive the motor should rotate CW. After reaching the limit switch, the motor is to be disconnected from the supply. Afterwards, by using a trigger (maybe reversing the supply, for example) the motor should rotate counterclockwise to reach the other limit switch. After reaching the switch, the motor should be disconnected from the supply again. By keeping the motor in this position and if we again give another trigger, the motor should rotate clockwise again.

In short, the motor should rotate to and fro. The limit switches should disconnect the motor when the knob reaches the limit switches. A trigger should be there to make the disconnected circuit live again.

The circuit is to be used in mostly damped areas place. The motor is actually closing a water connection valve. It can be easily done by using some microcontrollers. But if the microcontroller or any of the small components like we may use as switches(diode, MOSFETs etc..) fails, it may result in utter loss of water.

The motor has a maximum rating of 3.6VDC. And the supply is a 3.3V Li-ion Battery.

[image: The motor causes the knob to rotate which in turn pushes the limit switches.]

Comment: Why can't the circuit contain any active devices? This sounds very much like a homework problem, so you should show us all of the work you have done so far. Do you know how to connect a single limit switch to stop a motor traveling in one direction? If this is not a homework problem, explain how you will trigger the motor, give specifications for the power supply, provide a link to the motor's datasheet, and tell us about the mechanical load on the motor.

Comment: What is your *question* exacatly? If it is "Can you please design this for me?", please note this site is not a free design house.

Comment: Huge hint: a rectifier is not an active device.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The circuit is to be used in mostly damped areas place. The motor is actually closing a water connection valve. It can be easily done by using some microcontrollers. But if the microcontroller or any of the small components like we may use as switches(diode, MOSFETs etc..) fails, it may result in utter loss of water. So we want to make it by minimizing the components as far as we can. I have explained the functionality it requires. I made some circuits but none of them can reconnect the circuit to rotate motor again after turning it OFF using limit switches.

Comment: @Huisman I think the above comment clarifies the situation more. I am not wanting to design it for me, but I am rather stuck at that issue. Please have a look at the above comment, and thanks for your quick response.!!

Comment: Well, a *diode* is what is usually considered an *active component*, and you need two of them for this kind of stunt.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't make sense to me that you are willing to use a motor and mechanical switches in this damp environment but an "active device" is forbidden.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson this serves as a backup plan for the closure of the valve. Even if the controller fails, this circuit should work.

Comment: Two things.  First, clarify whether or not diodes are acceptable.  Second, what is the "trigger"?  For the diode circuit to work, the power supply connections must be reversible, requiring a DPDT switch of some kind (relay, MOSFET H-bridge, etc.)  How reliable is your non-active-device method?

Comment: @AnalogKid diodes are not acceptable. The trigger can be anything after which should make the motor to rotate in the opposite direction. -->> Like reversing the polarity of battery or something. The MOSFETS would require some gate voltage usually supplied by controllers to be ON  or OFF. I want to reduce the intervention of the controller in this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work for what you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPawtw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you assuming that the limit switches are normally open, as you have drawn them?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes..!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  I am sure the OP gets the idea.

Comment: @AmalnathSatyan Please add that information **to the original question**. The text of your question seems to imply that they are normally closed and "disconnect" the motor when it reaches the limit.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Updated

Comment: @HandyHowie... Let me check this, I think this should work..!! <3

Comment: @HandyHowie...It works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You need a circuit similar to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS8Ltc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Motor direction is selected by **SW**. The bumper switches **BSW1** and **BSW2** open as soon the respective end position is reached.

Comment: This will only provide 2.6V for the motor. Are you sure it will work?

Comment: There are 0.5V solar motors.

Comment: But why would I use those diodes?

Comment: The OP specified a motor with 3.6V max rating and a 3.3V battery.

Comment: A DC motor with a 3.6V maximum rating will run at roughly half the maximum speed at 1.8V. So it will function just fine at 2.6V.

Comment: Is that with or without a load? How can you be sure there is enough torque at half voltage? I think you are losing too much voltage in the diodes.

Comment: @Amalnath Satyan: You need the diodes so each bumper switch will only stop movement in its respective forward direction. You have to be able to move in the backward direction from the end position.

Comment: @Elliot Anderson: Torque is independent from speed in a permanent magnet DC motor as the one in the picture.

Comment: @Amalnath Satyan: As an alternative to diodes, you can use double-pole bumper switches and connect them to right row of individual contacts of **SW**, but the ones in your picture aren't double-pole, and they are hard to get your hands on.

Comment: I don't get your point. The fact that torque is independent of speed doesn't tell me what happens to torque if you cut the voltage in half, or to 2.6V.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson: The torque is independent from speed. If you cut the voltage in half you have half the speed, but the torque the motor can deliver is the same. This is why permanent magnet DC motors are used for low voltage DC applications.

Comment: //Torque is independent from speed in a permanent magnet DC motor as the one in the picture/// -->> true

Comment: @Janka Let me try with double-pole bumper switches

Comment: Interesting. Here I thought that torque was proportional to current, and the stall current was determined by the winding resistance, so the starting torque would also be reduced by lowering the voltage (and stall current).

Comment: There is an alternate method where one NC switch and diode (in parallel) is on each side of the motor.  Makes for easier field wiring.